# Odds of five board members voting the same way

Tags: probability

I have vote data for members of a board of directors. Five particular directors vote the same way 205times, out of 300.

The odds of five votes going the same way is 2/32 (all yes or all no). How can I figure out the odds of that happening 205 times out of 300?

Comment: [Odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) and [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) are not the same thing.  Did you mean probability?

Comment: What exactly are you asking and assuming?  Presumably board members do *not* vote randomly but actually consider the propositions.  so the probability of five votes going the same way is almost certainly *not* $\frac 2{32}$.

Comment: I do mean probability, and if I am thinking about correctly, in a given vote of five people, there are 2^5 or 32 possible outcomes, two of which are uniform, all yeas or all nays. I don't know how to calculate the probability of getting a 2/32 outcome at least 205 out of 300 times.

Comment: @LopelesslyHost / As fleablood pointed out, though, there may be 32 possibilities, 2 of which are favorable, but there is nothing here to tell us that the different possibilities are all equally likely. More plausibly, there is a shared ideology (or shared croney) contributing to their shared votes, and that throws the whole thing out of the realm of even fairly standard probability theory.

Answer (score 0):

Worded another way, if an event has a probability of $\frac{2}{32}$ of occurring, what is the probability of it occurring 205 out of 300 times? $$^{300}C_{205}*(\frac{2}{32})^{205}*(\frac{30}{32})^{95}$$